# array resets back mat checkbox - angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

i am trying to store the `checked value` in an array, it is an object since it also consists data for the row.

component.html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

component.ts

```
  close() {
    this.selectedData[this.data.myKey] = this.selection.myValue;
    this.roleOlsMap.push(this.selectedData);     // this resets back

  }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htyjdc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you open the dialog you are creating a new instance with new selection data, and this data is never saved outside the dialog instance. You need to save the selections with the row data and initialize the dialog with the selection when it is opened:

```
<mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
  (change)="$event ? toggleSelection(row) : null"
  [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
</mat-checkbox>


export class OlsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}
  listData: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['ols', 'actions'];

  selection = new SelectionModel<any>(true, this.data.selected);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(this.data.ols);
  }

  toggleSelection(row) {
    this.selection.toggle(row);
    this.data.selected = this.selection.selected;
  }
}
```

Comment: this works, one quick question, the `roleOlsMap` array, why is it getting reset after i close the dialog box.

Comment: As I said, it gets reinstantiated every time you open a dialog. The array isn't "reset", it is thrown away when you close the dialog. You weren't persisting that data anywhere, so it only exists for as long as the instance of the dialog exists.

Comment: hi there is a small issue with this solution, I can only select one checkbox at a time.

Comment: Different problem. It's because your selection model has multiple == false. Then you also need to change this.data.selected. See updated code.

Comment: yea when I make it true, i can multiselect but then again I lose the persistence.

Comment: it will be great if you can explain the SelectioModel a bit or how this works.

Comment: I've never used it before this. Maybe see https://jtrussell.io/angular-selection-model/.