# checkbox gets unchecked when I close dialog box - angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having a `Mat Table` which has an action column. The action column is a button which opens a `dialog box`.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htyjdc)

Inside the `dialog box`, I have another table with `checkbox`. When I make a selection(that is mark a row as `checked`) and close the `dialog box`, and when I return back to the same row, the selection is gone. It is reset. How to prevent this?

I have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htyjdc) example created to try this hands on.

Comment: because `OlsComponent` knows which items are checked via `selection`. when the dialog is closed, component is destroyed along with all of its data. and when you reopen the dialog a new instance is created. so your previous selection normally gets lost. what you can do is to store selection information somehow and when dialog is open re-initialize your selection model.

Comment: ^^ he is correct a modal is always supposed to be destoryed and created a new one you should pass data to he modal if you want to see it checked like this https://stackblitz.com/angular/bybjmdenlvl?file=app%2Fdialog-data-example.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array resets back mat checkbox - angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809286/array-resets-back-mat-checkbox-angular)

Comment: Why have you asked the same question twice? The answer is already here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56809957/9226213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're data structure is correct for what you're trying to achieve. This is your data row:

```
{ role: 'role1', ols: ['ols1', 'ols2'] },
```

How do you know from this, which `ols` is selected and which isn't?

I'd change your data structure to something like this:

```
{
    role: 'role1', ols: [
        {
            name: 'ols1',
            selected: false
        },
        {
            name: 'ols2',
            selected: false
        }
    ]
}
```

And change the binding for binding for the `mat-checkbox` to be `ngModel` so it is 2 way and remove everything else:

```
<mat-checkbox
   [(ngModel)]="row.selected">
</mat-checkbox>
```

Take a look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2kcgf3) StackBlitz illustration.